# including jquery

Tags: jquery

I know that wordpress ships with jquery. I have built my site first in html and every script that I have running in the html version works fine running version 1.4.2. I included this same jquery script and now one of my features don't work. This is how I am loading jquery into the head of my site

```
function register_savior_scripts(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('prettyPhoto', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('js-scripts',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('slider', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/coin-slider.min.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_head','register_savior_scripts', 0);
```

If I check the head, I see the script. It looks like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='full path removed/js/jquery.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>
```

It's not version 3.4.1. Not sure that matters. The script that it is running I put directly into the head and is this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".controls").click(function(e){
            if($(this).hasClass('down-arrow')) {
                $(this).addClass('up-arrow').removeClass('down-arrow');
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('down-arrow').removeClass('up-arrow');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#logo-background").slideToggle("slow");
        });
});
```

Is there a better way to load the script above into the head? Do you know why it would work on the html but not wordpress?

All it does is slide a div up or down to hide it if you press a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're deregistering jquery, then registering it under the handle `js-scripts`, but then specifying the `jquery` handle as a dependency for your other scripts. also, use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook for [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function, not `wp_head`. the appended version doesn't matter, but you can pass `null` as version parameter to get rid of it completely if you want.

Comment: well, I made the changes you suggested. Those were good ideas. I found that the reason the code isn't working is because of other scripts I have loading in the head section of my site. This is weird because it works just fine on the html version. Why would the WordPress version be any different?